# looping cross tab with error sign of not the same length

Tags: r, loops, crosstab

I tried to run a loop for cross tabs in R. But I kept getting an error sign saying that the length of my variables are different.

```
colnames(Comorbidity)
for(i in 1:86){
  Comorbidity_Variables=colnames(Comorbidity)[i]
  Comorbidity_Table <-  table(Comorbidity_Variables, Cognition$Sleep_De, exclude = c(NULL, NA))
  table(Comorbidity_Table)
  prop.table(Comorbidity_Table)
}
```

So I decided to run a crosstab with sleep deprivation against COPD. And, I got a result.

```
Comorbidity_Table <-  table(Comorbidity$CCC_COPD_COM, Cognition$Sleep_De)
table(Comorbidity_Table)
prop.table(Comorbidity_Table)
```

I am suspecting that there is something wrong with my loop. Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: Please include your data. It doesn't need to be your entire data set; just enough to allow folks to reproduce your loop and error.

Comment: `Comorbidity_Variables` is just a character vector / name not the variable itself, you will need to use something along the lines of `Comorbidity[[Comorbidity_Variables]]` in the `table` call